# how much pounds of pressure does a screw on perfume bottle cap vs a mechanically applied perfume bottle spray mechanism for a bottle exert?

Tags: applied-mechanics

What would be the difference in pressure between a screwed on bottle cap like the ones you see on a refillable perfume bottle screw on top such as this

https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/154178728592?hash=item23e5c4b290:g:AmIAAOSwhodfo8r2

vs a top that is closed with a mechanical pressurized tool such as this device

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000747195708.html

How much difference in pound/pressure per square inch would there be between the two in closing the top down onto the bottle?

I just need this for practical use, since I am looking to sell perfumes that I make

Is it a big difference in pressure per square inch? and how big? whats a way to calculate this difference?

and what friction would be created between the cap and the bottle so for example there isnt leakage , how do i calculate this difference?

1)how much friction does the bottle cap exert on the bottle from the screw on vs from the mechanically pressurized bottle cap onto the bottle from the mechanical device used to close the bottle caps?

2)what pressure or force would have to be provided on either for leakage?

how do i calculate these things? (1 and 2 and general question)

main concern is leakage of fluid from bottle and what point that occurs

Comment: The pressure change, or increase, will be down to the volume change once the seal has made sufficient contact.

Comment: Friction is not for preventing leakage.  Gaskets are.